# Why isn't this do-while loop working?

Tags: c++

Can someone explain to me why this do-while loop isn't working properly?

The program asks for an expression, then the program outputs the proper answer. After displaying the answer, the program asks the user if they want to perform another calculation. However, even if the user indicates that they do not want to perform the calculation again, the program loops anyway.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    float num_one;
    float num_two;
    char user_operator_one;
    char repeat;

    cout << "This is a very simple calculator." << endl;

    cout << "Please enter your expression: ";
    cin >> num_one >> user_operator_one >> num_two;
    cout << "\n\n";

    do
        {
            switch (user_operator_one)
                {
                case '+':
                    cout << num_one << "+" << num_two << "=" << num_one + num_two << endl;
                    break;

                case '-':
                    cout << num_one << "-" << num_two << "=" << num_one - num_two << endl;
                    break;

                case '*':
                    cout << num_one << "*" << num_two << "=" << num_one * num_two << endl;
                    break;

                case '/':
                    if (num_two == 0) {
                        cout << "Answer is undefined" << endl;
                    }
                    cout << num_one << "/" << num_two << "=" << num_one / num_two << endl;
                    break;

                default:
                    cout << user_operator_one << "is an unknown operation." << endl;
                    break;
                }

            cout << "Would you like to perform another operation (enter a 1 for yes, 0 for no.)";
            cin >> repeat;
        } while (repeat == 1);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you ask for `y` or `n` instead of `1` or `0`?

Comment: Also comparing two float like this `num_two == 0` is not a good idea

Comment: Even if you solve the repeating problem, there's another problem: you ask for the expression outside the loop, so it will keep giving the answer for the same expression.

Comment: Another problem: If you read a character, it will read the newline at the end of the expression, not the user's next input. You need to use `cin.ignore()` to skip past the newline and go to the next line of input.

Answer (score 4):

`repeat` is a `char`, you should test against `'1'`:

```
//...
while (repeat == '1');
```

Otherwise, you're testing against a decimal value of 1, which in the ASCII table is equivalent to an `SOH` or "Start of heading" character, which is not printable.

Additionally, you need to move your request for input to be *inside* the `do` portion of the loop:

```
do
{
    cout << "Please enter your expression: ";
    cin >> num_one >> user_operator_one >> num_two;
    cout << "\n\n";
    // ...
```

Comment: Or change the declaration to `int`.

Comment: If this was the issue, wouldn't the program not loop at all?

Comment: So the prompt should say "enter Ctl-a for yes" :)

Comment: @JGroven is right, the program shouldn't repeat at all. He'd get infinite repeating if he did `while (repeat != 0)`.

Comment: Gentlemen, while I agree with you, if you run the code, you'll notice that OP meant the opposite of what they said.

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
char repeat;
```

to

```
int repeat;
```

Comment: There's no need to initialize it, since it's not used before he does `cin >> repeat;`

Comment: You're 100% right. I've always been in habit of doing so ;)